# executescript problems when i will going to show this message

Tags: python-3.x, apache-nifi, apache-minifi

i use ExecuteScript for lunch this code

but this error appeared
o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=e0beca0c-0180-1000-7dbe-5ae9636e8ecf] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: NameError: name 'temperature' is not defined in  at line number 1: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: NameError: name 'temperature' is not defined in  at line number 1
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: NameError: name 'temperature' is not defined in  at line number 1
at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:254)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2khx.png)

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute that one line as a Jython script, but that isn't a valid script for an ExecuteScript Processor. Take a look at ScriptedTransformRecord, that might give you more of what you're looking for